# Unable to get NLog archive logs working

Tags: logging, nlog

I set up Nlog to archive on a monthly basis but when I change the clock (7/31/2011 to 8/1/2011) on the test machine and re-run my test it just writes the 8/1 log file and does not archive the 7/31 file.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Nlog.config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have included the date in the filename of your current log (as in the example).

```
<target name="file" 
        xsi:type="File" 
        fileName="${logDirectory}/${shortdate}.txt" 
        layout="${level} | ${message}" 
        archiveEvery="Day" 
        archiveFileName="${archiveDirectory}/${shortdate}.{###}.txt" 
        maxArchiveFiles="30" />
```

Archiving does not work ***if*** the date is included.

Answer (score 1):

If you do your configuration in code, you can have the filename contain a date string:

Like this:

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
target.FileName = string.Format("{0}{1}.csv", varLoggingFilePath, d);
target.ArchiveFileName = string.Format("{0}-{{####}}.csv", varLoggingFilePath, d);
```